# Generic Repository Pattern IEntity property case sensitivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am using Generic Repository Pattern in my application. I am trying this post http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/. The question is, database code generation tool (code first from existing database) generated following models:

```
[Table("TableName1")]
public partial class TableName1 : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ::::::::
}

[Table("TableName2")]
public partial class TableName2 : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ::::::::
}
```

And I just applied IEntity in above database models, but there is problem in TableName2 class because IEntity interface has 'ID' property not 'Id'. Here is the one

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; }
}
```

So how to convert this IEntity to accepts properties without looking at cases? I need easiest possible solution if I don't want to create separate independe new models for each table?

Comment: C# is case sensitive. Chage the column name in your persistence schema if you can.

Comment: Why would you want to do this ? It is against the idea of the interface and the database does not care about casing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a code first approach, Entity Framework will automatically pluralize your entity names when generating the tables, so lets add some context to your question first and remove all that abstraction, lets say we're creating a User repository, entity frameworks will automatically generate a `Users` table.

```
public partial class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class BlogPost : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

There is no way to bypass the casing rules, it is a rule, and as much as we like to be cowboys, what you wrote shouldn't even be able to compile as an `interface` is a **contract**. If a `class` implements a **contract**, it must implement everything that the **contract** outlines; the property `Id` with at least a `getter`.

I had a look at the link you supplied, and what it doesn't show you is how you should be implementing the `IRepository` properly, each of your entities should have its own repository, I would modify that interface to make it like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

What we have done here is we've said that `IRepository` will work with any Repository that implements `IRepository` accepting a `type parameter` which implements the `IEntity` contract.

```
public class UserRepository<User> : IRepository<User>
{ 
    protected Table<User> DataTable;

    public Repository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        DataTable = dataContext.GetTable<User>();
    }

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Insert(User entity)
    {
        DataTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(User entity)
    {
        DataTable.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<User> SearchFor(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DataTable.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return DataTable;
    }

    public User GetById(int id)
    {
        // Sidenote: the == operator throws NotSupported Exception!
        // 'The Mapping of Interface Member is not supported'
        // Use .Equals() instead
        return DataTable.Single(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I was using is overcome by Entity Framework itself now, not sure which version of Entity Framework. The code below shows a nice and clean implementation of the Generic Repository Pattern for the Entity Framework. There's no need for the IEntity interface here since we use the convenient Find extension method of the DbSet class.

So here is IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

And here is Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Leave the Entity Framework Code First codes as it is. Now, we are ready to use this Generic Repository in application, here's how:

```
using (var dataContext = new UserBaseContext())
{
    var userRepository = new Repository<Users>(dataContext);

    Users user = userRepository
        .SearchFor(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A"))
        .Single();

    //do other stuff

}
```

And this will not complain anything like casing etc, happy I have my first working generic repository :)